# The <ui-repeat> component disappears after an AJAX request

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I use JSF with PrimeFaces framework
I have a `<ui-repeat>` containing `<p:fieldset>`, when I filter `<p:fieldset>` with an AJAX query, the `<ui-repeat>` disappears from the page.

Here is my code :

```
<h:form id="myForm1">
    <p:panelGrid id="pnlg">
        <ui:repeat var="state" value="#{myBean.listState}" varStatus="status">
            <p:fieldset id="fieldsetState">
                <p:dataGrid id="dataGridState" value="#{myBean.state}">
                    <p:panel id="pnl">
                        // some code...
                    </p:panel>
                </p:dataGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>

<h:form id="myForm2">
    <p:commandButton value="Filter">
        // When I run this AJAX query, it is supposed to update 'myForm'. Instead, 'pnlg' disappears
        <p:ajax listener="#{ManageState.filterState}" update="myForm1" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

When I run this AJAX query, it is supposed to update 'myForm'. Instead, 'pnlg' disappears. I think it is because of `<ui:repeat>`.

Here is my backing Bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManageState extends AbstractManagedBean implements Serializable {
    public void filterState() {
        // Filter the list...
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class myBean implements Serializable {
    private List<sortedBean> listState;

    // getter, setter...
}
```

Comment: What does your backing bean look like? myBean is not in request scope, is it?

Comment: Also, don't know if it's a typo or meant like that, but I'm guessing your dataGrid value should be #{state} not #{myBean.state}

Comment: Hello, yes sorry it is a typo. I updated my post. Maybe you can tell me where the problem came from

Comment: The query works the first time and it filters the list. But the second time the <ui-repeat> disappears from the page. It's weird.

Comment: If I reload the page, the <ui-repeat> will not come back. Then I have to go to another page and come back to make it reappear.

Comment: ClientIDs are relative to their naming container. Your button is only looking for myForm1 inside myForm2. try update=":myForm1"

Comment: You could test even more... Does the `ui:repeat` content disappear or even the panel itself (your title and description are contradicting eachother)? Then you can test even more. Does plain content in the panel disappear? What if you have static content in the `myForm1` and no panel (just plain text)

Comment: I tried to update the form with ':' but it does not works.@Kukeltje I will do the test to check.

Comment: Everything in the `<ui-repeat>` disappears from the page after the AJAX request. The `<h: form id = "myForm1">` and `<p: panelGrid id = "pnlg">` remain.
What is curious is that the bug appears at the end of the second time. The first time it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, merged the two forms and it works. But I do not know exactly why he behaves this way.